# Android Library project says nullpointerexception

Tags: android, android-library

I have an android library project `my_lib` basically `my_lib` has `list activity` say `MyListActivity` it has resources and stuffs. when I run as android application 'MyListActivity' works fine.

but when I create another `proj` say `test_proj` and make `my_lib` as android library project and add to `test_proj` as library and added `MyListActivity` activity in `AndroidManifest` and run I am getting `NullPoiterException` in `MyListActivity`, i.e at `findViewById(R.id.list)` is returning null. how can I fix this

Code is as below

onCreate Of MyListActivity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initData();

rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i], packageNames[i]);
    rowItems.add(item);
}

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

}

onCreate of MainActivity of test proj

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ImageTextListViewActivity.class));

}
```

Error Log is as below

```
D/AndroidRuntime(  778): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(  778): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  778): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.mass.applist.R$id.list
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at com.mass.applist.MyListActivity.onCreate(MyListActivity.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime(  778):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your code and logcat error trace.

Comment: 2 different R.java files are created in this situation. One in your `my_lib` project and other in `test_project`. In your `test_project` you are trying to access resource that are defined in `my_lib` library project.

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal I am not calling any resource in my test_appm, I am calling Activity which is in lib

Comment: Can you explain how are you adding it as Android Library and how have you setup your project as library. Have you done this by right click-> Properties->Android-> check "is Library"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

make sure layout in lib and your sample activity does not have same name.